# How to use auto return and decltype when class members involved with c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype, trailing-return-type

For example

```
struct A
{
    auto count() -> decltype(m_count) { return m_count; }
    int m_count;        
};
```

The above gets compilation error because m_count in `decltype` is not recognized. How to work around it? `auto` return and get the type from `m_count` must be used.

The code compiles when the order is changed

```
struct A
{
    int m_count;        
    auto count() -> decltype(m_count) { return m_count; }
};
```

but how do I get the first case to work?

Comment: When I use this simple version, it is okay now. May be bugs in other where. THanks.

Comment: Now that you edited, the answer is simple : the compiler doesn't know the name `m_count`, so the declarations must be reordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you can't use a name that hasn't been introduced (declared) in a declaration, including in a `decltype` for a trailing return type. So you must reorder your declarations :

```
struct A
{
    int m_count;
    auto count() -> decltype(m_count) { return m_count; }
};
```

Comment: you can use it though in a function body, but not in a declaration

Answer (score 3):

The trailing return type is part of the *member function declaration*, and not the *member function definition* (***[dcl.fct]/2***). That's the reason why you can use `m_count` within the function body even when the data member follows the member function definition.

However, when used in a declaration, the name in question must be declared before its use.

*§3.4.1/7* ***[basic.lookup.unqual]***

> A name used in the definition of a class `X` outside of a member function body or nested class definition shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>   — before its use in class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2), or
>   — `...`

In your case, you need to place the declaration of `m_count` ahead of `count()`; or if you have access to a C++14 compiler, you can omit the trailing return type altogether.

```
struct A
{
    auto count() { return m_count; } // OK in C++14
    int m_count;        
};
```